# './configure: no such file or directory' when I try to install firefox from tar.bz2 file

Tags: command-line, software-installation

Downloaded and unpacked `firefox-57.0b13.tar.bz2` into Downloads/firefox.
No install or readme instructions found there.
Attempted to install using

```
./configure
make
make install
```

When I enter `./configure`, I get `no such file or directory`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why exactly don't you just install it using `sudo apt install firefox`?

Comment: It's probably containing a binary. Look for an executable file named `firefox`

Comment: Nitpicking: It's not the terminal that answers this. It's your _shell_ answering (instructing the terminal to display) this error message, the terminal obeys and displays it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

It has a binary file called **firefox**. Double click to open it or type `./firefox` in terminal. It's precompiled. It doesn't need to be installed.